# How to send multiple link to facebook debugger

Tags: facebook, debugging

I have a website with some dynamic urls (for example a page who show event details thanks to event id in get variable), but during the share with facebook, at the first attempt the thumbnail image doesn't appear due the page isn't already fetched by facebook.
Then I must go to the debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and submit every pages to get a valid thumbnail to the users.
There's a script or a way to send multiple links to this debugger, or there's another way to achieve the indexing of new pages by facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refresh the Open Graph tags with a POST request to the Graph API, i think it´s not in the Facebook docs (at least i could not find it) - but it definitely works:

```
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com', {
    id: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/somefile.html',
    scrape: true
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Just an example with jQuery, of course you can just use CURL on the server too.